# Creating Ubuntu 12.04 DEB-package for program with system tray icon

Tags: linux, packaging, system-tray, ubuntu-unity

I have wrote a program in **Lazarus** (Free Pascal) for Ubuntu 12.04. This program has an icon in system tray bar, but by default icon is not visible there. How can I compose a ***.deb** package in order to **Unity** desktop environment allows the system tray icon for my program?

Please, do not advise me to use **Dconf-editor** for this purpose because it's a user way, but I need to know a standard way (approved by **Canonical**) for deploying such ***.deb**-packages.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible - Canonical want you using indicators rather than tray icons now, IIRC.

Comment: If this is true, then it is a very stupid policy

Comment: http://design.canonical.com/2010/04/notification-area/

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you want to include indicator-applet for your program, But unfortunately pascal binding for indicator applet is not available yet